# Some bold and some simple word within the same statement

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I want to show some bold and some simple word within the same sentence.If I use the textbox
then every word will be simple, not some bold and some simple so I want a control's text
property in that I can write some bold and some simple word within the same statement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had need like in one control I want to show the content with some bold and some simple font and some colorful so for that I have used ***webbrowser*** on that window form and I could satisfy my every requirement with the ***webbrowser control***.Because we can set***html*** content to the ***webbrowser's DocumentText*** property.And in html content we can make font ***bold,simple as well as colorful*** with same sentense.

We can use richtextbox also.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like a [RichTextBox](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/WPFRichTextBox09072008194855PM/WPFRichTextBox.aspx) is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 2):

You should use rich text box, read [this](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/duncanharris/SyntaxHighlightInRichTextBoxP112012005050840AM/SyntaxHighlightInRichTextBoxP1.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Is this for Web or Desktop? With desktop you want to use the [RichTextControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3tdc88y7.aspx) on the web I am not sure you can do it in a textbox, but you can use HTML and the label control to produce the same effect. Not sure about WPF I have never used that.

Answer (score 0):

Hai harikrishna,
   you can use javascript text editors or jquery.. A list of jquery and non-jquery editors can be found in this link
http://www.queness.com/post/212/10-jquery-and-non-jquery-javascript-rich-text-editors